# Implementing Linked List in JAVA (Reverse without using iterator)

Tags: java

I am trying to implement the linkedList class, adding a method reverse(int n) to reverse the linked list. For example, I have a linked list { A -> B -> C -> D -> E). When I call reverse(4), the linked list will become D-->C-->B-->A-->E.

I am trying to avoid using iterator, constructing new node and copying the data value. Does anyone have idea how to do it? I know there was a post about reversing linked list but that one is reversing the entire linked list.

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Just use the same principle.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide your implementation of the `LinkedList`, i can only provide the general idea:
The complete list can be reversed by simply swaping the pointers to the previous node and the next node and updating the fields for the last and first node.

```
void reverse()
    node tmp = first
    first = last
    last = tmp

    while(tmp.next != null)
        node swap = tmp.next
        tmp.next = tmp.previous
        tmp.previous = swap

        tmp = swap
```

I'll leave it to you to add the bounds